# Oracle SQL -- look for new users that were not shown in last week

Tags: sql, oracle

I generate report in XL sheet every week, using a DB which tracks the users of a website. I have to find the list of my web application users who didn't show up in previous report, which was generated last week.

DB Structure with data(table has two columns **WebAppUserName** and **URL**):

```
WebAppUserName           URL  
Tom                       google.com
```

first week Data in DB:

```
  Tom                      google.com
  Jim                      google.com/test
  Ken                      google.com/test
```

Second week (last week)Data in DB:

```
  Tom                      google.com
  Jim                      google.com/test
```

This week(Third week) Data in DB:

```
 Tom                      google.com
 Jim                      google.com/test
 Ken                    google.com/test
 Ron                    google.com/test
```

Since Ken and Ron didn't appeared in the last week Data and they both appeared in this week data, >I need to retrieve only Ken and Ron's information and not the other users. How to write a Query for >this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is no way we can answer your question currently.  Here's some info about [creating a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is the DB Structure with sample data: 
WebAppUserName                URL
Tom                                        google.com

Comment: I certainly hope this isn't your database structure. At the least, there are no dates.

Comment: sorry for not adding the date column. But it is there in the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be date column in your table to identify when user accessed the URL.

You can use `not exists` something like following

```
Select t.* from
Your_table t
Where trunc(t.date,'IW') = trunc(SYSDATE,'IW') -- fetch current week data
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 
FROM YOUR_TABLE TT
WHERE trunc(t.date,'IW') - trunc(TT.date,'IW') = 7 -- exclude user who appeared last week
AND TT.WEBAPPUSERNAME = T.WEBAPPUSERNAME) -- you can also add condition for URL in not exists if required in your logic
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

`row_number()` is a typical solution:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by WebAppUserName order by datecol) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Often a correlated subquery has the good performance:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.datecol = (select min(t2.datecol)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.WebAppUserName = t.WebAppUserName
                  );
```